# Why is dual-scale plotting so complicated per the official function?

Tags: plotting, graphics, rescale

The page ["How to | Generate Plots with Two Vertical Scales"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales.html) describes an official recommended way to plot two functions with different vertical axis scales.  The solution, in my opinion, is hideous:

```
TwoAxisPlot[{f_, g_}, {x_, x1_, x2_}] := 
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, gticks},

{fgraph, ggraph} = MapIndexed[Plot[#, {x, x1, x2}, Axes -> True, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]] &, {f, g}];
{frange, grange} = (PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])[[2]] & /@ {fgraph, ggraph};
fticks = N@FindDivisions[frange, 5]; 
gticks = Quiet@Transpose@{fticks, ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm] & /@ Rescale[fticks, frange, grange]}; 
Show[fgraph, ggraph /. Graphics[graph_, s___] :> Graphics[
GeometricTransformation[graph, RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s],
Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]
```

I made it a bit more readable, with only one change in functionality (add the ability to specify the range of each plot manually) below:

```
TwoAxisPlot[{f_, g_}, {x_, x1_, x2_}, fRange_ : Automatic, gRange_ : Automatic] := 
 Module[{plotInput, fPlot, gPlot, gPlotScaled, fRangeUsed, gRangeUsed, fTicks, gTicks},

  plotInput = {{f, g}, ColorData[1][#] & /@ {1, 2}, {fRange, gRange}};
  {fPlot, gPlot} = MapThread[Plot[#1, {x, x1, x2}, Axes -> True, PlotStyle -> #2, PlotRange -> #3] &, plotInput];
  {fRangeUsed, gRangeUsed} = Last @@@ Values[AbsoluteOptions[{fPlot, gPlot}, PlotRange]];
  gPlotScaled = Graphics[GeometricTransformation[First[gPlot],
     RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, gRangeUsed}, {{0, 1}, fRangeUsed}]], Last[gPlot]];
  fTicks = N[FindDivisions[fRangeUsed, 5]];
  gTicks = ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm] & /@ Rescale[fTicks, fRangeUsed, gRangeUsed];
  Show[fPlot, gPlotScaled, Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
    FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1][#] & /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
    FrameTicks -> {{fTicks, Transpose[{fTicks, gTicks}]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]
```

I've seen questions about how this function works on other StackOverflow posts, with no answers except that it's per the official documentation.  The part that was particularly confusing was:

```
Show[fgraph, ggraph /. Graphics[graph_, s___] :> Graphics[...
```

It turns out that `Head[Plot[x,{x,0,1}]` ***IS*** a `Graphics[graph_, s___]` object; the above `Replace` is just plain *weird* and definitely confusing to a newbie.

**Is there any loss of generality with the readability changes I've made???**

It seems like this is a feature that almost everybody would eventually need to use, even high-school level users, and it's very convoluted if you're not a Mathematica guru.  Granted, you can "just use it", but it's not very general-case, and if you want to modify it, you have to understand it to some degree at least.

Comment: In version 12, there is the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction.html) for [`MultipleAxesPlot`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultipleAxesPlot)

Comment: And also [`CombinePlots`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots).

Comment: These sound exciting -- I've never heard of them, thanks!